# Upper-bound wildcard (extends) not working; ArrayList<? extends SuperType> doesn't allow instances of subtype

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, bounded-wildcard

From what I know of bounded wildcards, a type parameter of `<? extends Object>` would accept all types that are subtypes of `Object`. As the Java Tutorials states:

> The upper bounded wildcard, `<? extends Foo>`, where Foo is any type, matches Foo and any subtype of Foo

So if I had the type `GridPosition`, which extends `Position`, `? extends Position` should accept the type `GridPosition`.

**The Problem**

While attempting to add an instance of `GridPosition extends Position` to a list declared with the type `ArrayList<? extends Position>`, I get an error:

> The method `add(capture#1-of ? extends Position)` in the type `ArrayList<capture#1-of ? extends Position>` is not applicable for the arguments (`GridPosition`)

The code I'm referring to, in simplest form:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<? extends Position> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new GridPosition()); // Error on this line
    }
}

class Position {}
class GridPosition extends Position {}
```

A picture of the error in `Eclipse Luna` running `Java 8u31`:

[image]

Is this a bug? Or am I not understanding bounded wildcards?

---

I've noticed that `? super Position` allows me to add instances of `GridPosition` to the list.

When using a list with the type argument of `<? extends Position>`, no the instances (from the classes below) work:

```
class Super {}
class Position extends Super {}
class GridPosition extends Position {}
```

Picture:

[image]

Comment: For this case use `ArrayList<Position>` and let duck-typing handle it. It's not a bug, but I can't properly explain why it doesn't work. Something with Generics needing you to specify a type in order to operate on an instance

Comment: @Felk I'm not looking for an answer, rather than an explanation for future record. I've used upper-bound wildcards in the past and have never came across this problem. The tutorial even states that it `<? extends Foo>` matches subtypes of `Foo`. I'm not sure if something has changed, or if I'm not understanding something. `Class<? extends Position> clazz = GridPosition.class` works fine

Comment: @VinceEmigh? `List<? extends Position>` means a list of some _unknown but specific_ subtype of `Position`.  It could, for example, be a `List<SomeOtherSubtypeOfPosition>`, which it wouldn't make sense to add a `GridPosition` too.  That's what `List<? extends Position>` means.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `super` if you want to add to a generic List. `extends` is for read (get and etc) operations. You can find details in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility

Comment: I think this is more of a best practice (as in: how to write better APIs), but it does not really answer the question. No, I don't have the book at hand.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what a read operation is? How would the declared type play a role in `get` operations?

Comment: From the article I mentioned: if a parameterized type represents a T producer, use <? extends T>;
if it represents a T consumer, use <? super T>.